# How can I make my CSS update consistently?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

When I click on a button my layout falls apart. When I click on a button the CSS breaks apart my layout. How do I update my CSS to layout my divs properly?

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  totalCount = 100;
  for (var i = 0; i < totalCount; i++) {
    var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    newDiv.innerHTML = "Number " + i;
    var applyClass = "bgColor"; //Identify the class
    document.getElementById("mainContainer").appendChild(newDiv);
    newDiv.id = "div" + i;
    document.getElementById(newDiv.id).className = applyClass;
    $('#div' + i).click(callbackFunction());
  }

  function callbackFunction(e) {
    return function() {
      //Remove all instances of css
      for (var i = 0; i < totalCount; i++) {
        $("#div" + i).removeClass('newColor');
      }
      document.getElementById(this.id).classList.add('newColor');
    }
  }
});
```

```css
div {
  background-color: #ff0;
  padding: 2px;
  font-size: 12px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 2px;
  margin-right: 2px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out
}
.newColor {
  background-color: #00ffff;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-left: 6px;
  margin-right: 6px;
  margin-top: 28px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body id="mainContainer">

</body>
```

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "properly"?

Comment: Do they have to increase in size?

Comment: Yes, that will be important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achive this by removing

```
 float
```

and making your div like this.

```
 div {
        background-color: #ff0;
        padding:2px;
        font-size:12px;
        word-wrap: break-word;//this one too. incase the word becomes too long.
        display: inline-block;//this one has been added.
        margin-left: 2px;
        margin-right: 2px;
        margin-top: 30px;
        width:auto;
        padding: 5px;
        cursor:pointer;
        -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
        transition: all .5s ease-in-out
    }
```

Comment: For the "word-wrap" addition ;-) def a +1

Answer (score 1):

I think i know what you want, try this :

```
    .newColor {
        background-color: #00ffff;
        font-size:16px;
        margin-left: 6px;
        margin-right: 6px;
        margin-top: 26px;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Please tell me why this is necessary. How could I have solved this on my own using Firebug or something similar?

Comment: @SimonRH - I still get a flicker effect when clicking on elements when just using this. You should just have to change "float: left" on your div for "display: inline-block"

Comment: Its about understanding the box-model approach to web design more than knowing how to investigate using the inspector. Try googling how margins and paddings effect each element, its parent and siblings etc ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use `display:inline-block` instead...

```
   div {
        background-color: #ff0;
        padding:2px;
        font-size:12px;
        display:inline-block; // CHANGED THIS
        margin-left: 6px;
        margin-right: 6px;
        margin-top: 30px;
        padding: 5px;
        cursor:pointer;
        -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
        transition: all .5s ease-in-out
    }        
    .newColor {
        background-color: #00ffff;
        font-size:16px;
        margin-left: 6px;
        margin-right: 6px;
        margin-top: 27px;
        padding: 5px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS `margin-top` on the `.newColor` class was out by just 1 pixel.

Try my amended code below

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  totalCount = 100;
  for (var i = 0; i < totalCount; i++) {
    var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    newDiv.innerHTML = "Number " + i;
    var applyClass = "bgColor"; //Identify the class
    document.getElementById("mainContainer").appendChild(newDiv);
    newDiv.id = "div" + i;
    document.getElementById(newDiv.id).className = applyClass;
    $('#div' + i).click(callbackFunction());
  }

  function callbackFunction(e) {
    return function() {
      //Remove all instances of css
      for (var i = 0; i < totalCount; i++) {
        $("#div" + i).removeClass('newColor');
      }
      document.getElementById(this.id).classList.add('newColor');
    }
  }
});
```

```css
div {
  background-color: #ff0;
  padding: 2px;
  font-size: 12px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 2px;
  margin-right: 2px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out
}
.newColor {
  background-color: #00ffff;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-left: 6px;
  margin-right: 6px;
  margin-top: 26px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body id="mainContainer">

</body>
```

Comment: It does not work for  margin-top: 27px; but it does work for  margin-top: 26px;

Comment: Works fine on the latest chrome but sure ill amend

Comment: Fails in Firefox 38.2.0

Comment: Ahh, well its amended so should be all good now :)